# Boundedness of Liouville function sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to prove that $|\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{n}|$ < 2, where $\lambda$ is the Liouville function,and n is integral. I have shown ,using Divisor Sum Identities, that for $x \geq 1$,$
\sum_{n \leq x}\lambda(n)[\frac{x}{n}] =[\sqrt{x}]$,but cannot see how to proceed.
`

Comment: Hint: use $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\lambda(n)}n = \frac1x \sum_{n\le x} \lambda(n) \lfloor \frac xn \rfloor + \frac1x \sum_{n\le x} \lambda(n) \bigl( \frac xn - \lfloor \frac xn \rfloor \bigr)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint; it leads quickly to the required result.

Comment: If this is for homework, remember to credit your sources.

Comment: No,this is for private research into the order of multiplicative functions

Comment: Numerical data suggest that $|\sum_{n \leq x} \lambda(n)/n| \leq 1$ for all $x \geq 1$.  On the MO page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198404/bound-on-a-scaled-sum-of-the-liouville-function one answer gives the bound $1 + 1/\sqrt{x}$ and another answer gives the bound $1$.